# Why doesn't my view controller fill the whole screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello everyone I'm fairly new to Xcode. Whenever I add a ViewController and perform a segue to it from a previous screen it looks like this.

[Pic of ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKSnS.png)

I would like it to look full screen instead of having it slide up and down.

[This is the View its connected to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3aZ4.png)

This is the code.

```
if loginMode{
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
             if error == nil {
                 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "authSuccess", sender: nil)
             } else {
                 //print(error)
             }
         }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

iOS 13 change the animation

try this

```
  let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "example")
  VC1.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
  self.navigationController!.present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you present it do this

```
YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```